# Method setState() is not updating the UI (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, setstate, flutter-widget

My home screen is a Scaffold with a ListView at its body and a floating action button at the bottom. The action button takes the user to a second screen, where he can type a text into a text input and press save. The save button calls a method at the home screen that adds the text to the List variable over which ListView is based. The problem is: the List variable is being updated (I can see on the log), but the setState is not updating the ListView. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code from the Home Screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'addCounter.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
    
    List lista = <Widget>[];

    void incrementLista(newItem) {
      print('$lista');
      setState(() {
        lista.add(Box('newItem'));
      });
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List of Counters'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[1000],
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context)=>
       Center(
            child: ListView(children: lista),
          ),),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[1000],
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => AddCounter(f: incrementLista)));
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white)),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[700],
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            title: Text('Lista'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
            title: Text('Gráfico'),
          ),
        ],
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the code from the addCounter.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function f;
  AddCounter({@required this.f});

  @override
  _AddCounterState createState() => _AddCounterState();
}

class _AddCounterState extends State<AddCounter> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add a counter'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: TextField(
              controller: myController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2)),
                  hintText: 'Type a name for the counter'),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.green,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.f(myController.text);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              'Save',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

I don't think the code for the Box widget is relevant. It is basically a card with a title.

Comment: Share the AddCounter's code too.

Comment: `lista` is a list of `Widget`s? if so, you need to create a brand new list each time `setState` is called

Comment: Hi @theCaptainXgod! I just shared the AddCounter's code!

Comment: basically you should not use such a list of widgets, data and presentation layers should be separated, instead you should use a list of data only, see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible for more info

Comment: Hi, @pskink, yes, `lista` is a list of a custom widgets named `Box`. To create a `Box` I must pass a `String` as an argument.

Comment: so use a list of strings only and build your `Box`es inside `build` method, check the link i posted above - they remove list's items but the idea is the same

Comment: @pskink, it works!!! I have been stuck on this problem for days, without a clue! You don't know how much you helped me, thank you very much! I don't want to abuse your patience, but could you explain to me why it is necessary to separate the data and presentation layers?

Comment: this is more or less forced by a flutter's design under the hood

Answer (score 2):

@pskink gave me an answer that worked perfectly. Here it is:

basically you should not use such a list of widgets, data and presentation layers should be separated, instead you should use a list of data only, see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible for more info